# Liferay 6.1 with Glassfish 3.1.2: IllegalStateException: Must call associate() before calling activate()

Tags: primefaces, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3, netbeans-7, liferay-6

I want to ask what is wrong with my code. I was having problems regarding **IllegalStateException** in my project. My set up is as follows:

- Netbeans 7.2.1 + JSF 2
- Liferay 6.1 GA2 bundled with Glassfish 3.1.2
- Primefaces 3.5

I use the 'Entity from Database' function to generate my entities.

I have been trying to find the solution for this for a long time and I always get info about issues in jboss. But most posts are about 1 ~ 2 years old and some of them said that it was already resolved.

Here are my codes:

**PleaseBean.java**

```java
package please.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import please.model.CoopProspect;
import please.util.CoopProspectFacade;


@ManagedBean(name="pleaseBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PleaseBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CoopProspect prospect;
    private CoopProspect[] selectedProspects;
    private CoopProspect selectedProspect;
    private List<CoopProspect> prospectList;
    private List<CoopProspect> filteredProspect;
    private transient DataModel<CoopProspect> prospectModel;
    private CoopProspectFacade prospectFacade;


    public PleaseBean() {
        prospect = new CoopProspect();
        prospectList = prospectFacade.findAll();
        prospectModel = new ListDataModel<CoopProspect>(prospectList);
    }

    public String create() {
        prospectFacade.create(prospect);
        prospect = new CoopProspect();
        refreshList();
        return "";
    }

    public void editMode() {
        prospect = selectedProspect;
    }

    public void refreshList() {
        prospectList = prospectFacade.findAll();
        prospectModel = new ListDataModel<CoopProspect>(prospectList);
    }


    public void save() {
        editMode();
        prospectFacade.edit(prospect);
        prospect = new CoopProspect();
    }

    public void delete() {
        prospectFacade.remove(selectedProspects);
        refreshList();
    }

    public List<CoopProspect> getProspectList() {
        return prospectList;
    }


    public void setFilteredProspectList(List<CoopProspect> filteredProspect) {
        this.filteredProspect = filteredProspect;
    }

    public List<CoopProspect> getFilteredProspectList() {
        return filteredProspect;
    }

    public DataModel<CoopProspect> getProspectModel() {
        if (prospectModel == null) {
            prospectModel = new ListDataModel<CoopProspect>(prospectList);
        }
        return prospectModel;
    }

    public CoopProspect getProspect() {
        if (prospect == null) {
            prospect = new CoopProspect();
        }
        return prospect;
    }

    public CoopProspect[] getSelectedProspects() {
        return selectedProspects;
    }

    public void setSelectedProspects(CoopProspect[] selectedProspects) {
        this.selectedProspects = selectedProspects;
    }

    public CoopProspect getSelectedProspect() {
        if (selectedProspect == null) {
            selectedProspect = new CoopProspect();
        }
        return selectedProspect;
    }

    public void setSelectedProspect(CoopProspect selectedProspect) {
        this.selectedProspect = selectedProspect;
    }

}
```

---

**AbstractFacade.java**

```java
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package please.util;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

/**
 *
 * @author mis
 */
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public boolean remove(T[] entities) {
        for(T entity: entities) {
            getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
        }
        return true;
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        CriteriaQuery cq =
                getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        CriteriaQuery cq =
                getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        CriteriaQuery cq =
                getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }
}
```

---

**CoopProspectFacade.java**

```java
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package please.util;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import please.model.CoopProspect;

@Stateless
public class CoopProspectFacade extends AbstractFacade<CoopProspect> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "please1PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public CoopProspectFacade() {
        super(CoopProspect.class);
    }
}
```

---

**Index.xhtml**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="adform">
                <p:panelGrid styleClass="nameruna" >
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="datepros" value="Date: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:calendar id="datepros" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.prosDate}" readonlyInput="true" required="true" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel  for="fname" value="Firstname: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="fname" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.firstName}" required="true" size="25" maxlength="25"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="mname" value="Middlename: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="mname" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.middleName}" size="20" maxlength="20"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="lname" value="Lastname: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="lname" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.lastName}" required="true" size="20" maxlength="20"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="gender" value="Gender: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneRadio id="gender" required="true" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.gender}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="M"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="F"/>
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="bday" value="Date of birth: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:calendar id="bday" 
                                        value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.birthdate}" 
                                        navigator="true" 
                                        readonlyInput="true" 
                                        pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" 
                                        yearRange="c-100:c+0"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="cntno" value="Contact number: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="cntno" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.contactNumber}" size="12" maxlength="12"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="los" value="Length of stay is two years? "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="los" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.lengthOfStay}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="natl" value="Nationality: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="natl" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.nationality}" required="true" size="8" maxlength="8"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="orgu" value="Organizational Unit: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="orgu" required="true" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.ouCode}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="PT01" itemValue="PT01"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h2>
                            <h:outputText value="ADDRESS"/>
                            </h2>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="street" value="Street/Phase: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="street" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.street}" size="60" maxlength="60"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="bgy" value="Barangay: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="bgy" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.barangay}" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="city" value="City/Municipality: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="city" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.cityMun}" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="regn" value="Region: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="regn" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.region}" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="provnc" value="Province: "/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="provnc" value="#{pleaseBean.prospect.province}" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{pleaseBean.create}"
                                             value="Submit"
                                             onclick="adform.reset()"
                            />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

---

Stack Trace

```
2013-03-07T06:11:31.122+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=177;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ApplicationDispatcher[/please1-portlet] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet please1 Servlet threw exception
javax.portlet.faces.BridgeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must call associate() before calling activate()
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:193)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:85)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:112)
    at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:255)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:204)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:807)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:556)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:534)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:607)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:359)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1174)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:807)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:556)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.include(DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:90)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:54)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:5158)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:5116)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1557)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.RenderPortletAction.execute(RenderPortletAction.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.UpdateLayoutAction.addPortlet(UpdateLayoutAction.java:334)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.UpdateLayoutAction.getJSON(UpdateLayoutAction.java:287)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.JSONAction.execute(JSONAction.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:560)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:537)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:335)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:216)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must call associate() before calling activate()
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.activate(AbstractConversationContext.java:200)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.execute(LifecycleWrapper.java:35)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:185)
    ... 138 more
```

---

Can anyone help me?

Note: This is NOT a good coding example and must not be emulated by anyone.

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: I updated with my stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this error indicates that CDI (JBoss Weld) is getting activated which is currently not compatible with a portlet environment. Recommend that you look for a WEB-INF/beans.xml descriptor in your WAR artifact or META-INF/beans.xml in any of the JAR files in the ClassPath. If you find any, they need to be removed. Hopefully we will have CDI compatibility soon with [FACES-1211](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1211).